# trouble calling the correct instances in my function and in my "moveTo" block

Tags: anylogic

I want to fill a pie chart but am having trouble calling the correct instances in my function and in my "moveTo" block.

I have a function that returns nothing (just action) with the name AGVundTyp.
This is my function body:

```
if ((Package)agent.p_type==0 && ((AGV)agent.p_type==0)) {
    AGV1_Type1++; 
} else if ((Package)agent.p_type==1 && ((AGV)agent.p_type==0)){
    AGV1_Type2++; 
} else if ((Package)agent.p_type==2 && ((AGV)agent.p_type==0)){
    AGV1_Type3++;
} 
else { 
    error ("error"); 
}


if ((Package)agent.p_type==0 && ((AGV)agent.p_type==1) ){
    AGV2_Type1++; 
} else if ((Package)agent.p_type==1 && ((AGV)agent.p_type==1)){
    AGV2_Type2++; 
} else if ((Package)agent.p_type==2 && ((AGV)agent.p_type==1)){
    AGV2_Type3++;
} 
else { 
    error ("error");    
}

if ((Package)agent.p_type==0 && ((AGV)agent.p_type==2)) {
    AGV3_Type1++; 
} else if ((Package)agent.p_type==1 && ((AGV)agent.p_type==2)){
    AGV3_Type2++; 
} else if ((Package)agent.p_type==2 && ((AGV)agent.p_type==2)){
    AGV3_Type3++;
} 
else { 
    error ("error");
```

I have the error messages:

- agent cannot be resolved to a variable
- Incompatible operand types AGV and int
- Incompatible operand types Packages and int

I have in my class AGV a parameter with p_type (int) and in my class Package also a parameter with p_type (int) .

The initialization of the types of package were set in the source at creation.

The initialization of the types of AGV was set in the respective resource pool. There are three different ResourcePool (for each type of AGV one ResourcePool).

The function should be called in the moveTo operator and compare the two types of orders respectively. Since I have the same parameters, I don't know how to call it so that it clearly distinguishes which type of AGV/package is meant.

How do I solve my problem that I can compare the agents properly and add them in my pie chart?

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: As before, try to simplify your root problem. This is typically too much to take in and help you with (there are several issues here). Avoid writing big functions and creating complex models and then seek help. Start simple, add tiny bits of features, test test test. This will ensure that it is only small issues you get stuck with (which we can help here easily)...

In other words: Try to make *our* lives easy, not yours :) See https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow 

(Sorry for pushing back but I want to ensure you get the most out of SOF :) )

Answer (score 2):

there are a lot of problems here... some examples:

```
if ((Package)agent.p_type==0 && ((AGV)agent.p_type==0)) {
```

you can't just cast an agent to whatever you want instead you should do something like this

```
if(agent instanceof Package){

}else if(agent instanceof AGV){

}
```

Second use a collection or arrays instead of raw variables to count
instead of `AGV1_Type2++;`

```
AGV[1][2]++;
```

You also need to be sure that agent is an input to your function, and it has to be of the type Agent so you can cast it to different things within the function

You have probably 10 other errors... so make sure you know what you are doing, simplify and test smaller chunks of code in order to see what you are doing wrong